# How to increase interrupt sampling frequency on Beagle Bone Black?

Tags: interrupt, encoder, beagleboneblack

Currently I'm attempting to read a 600ppr optical encoder with a simple attachInterrupt() function through the built in Cloud 9 IDE (node.js), the issue is that if the rotary encoder is rotated too quickly the position data becomes lost; it appears that the frequency of the signal provided by the encoder exceeds the interrupt's sampling rate.

My question is there a way to increase the sampling rate to somewhere in the range of 100KHz, currently it seems to sample at roughly 2KHz.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you perhaps CPU bound? Could you SSH to the device and look at CPU utilization, e.g. using linux' `top` command?

Comment: It is limited by the CPU, from my understanding, normal CPU interrupts are slow and inefficient. The ARM chip on the BeagleBone contains two PRU cores running at 200MHz, I'm currently trying to utilize those for my project.